# How to calculate this summation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I need to calculate this summation:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n\cdot n!}$$

I know the answer without the excess $n$ in the denominator, i.e.  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!}=e^a-1$.

Comment: Check the exponential integral.

Comment: Do you mean $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}}{n \cdot n!}$$ Else you have $\frac{1}{0}$ as your first term?

Comment: @Shaktal You are right, I just edited the question. The summation is from $n=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you meant $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}}{n\cdot n!}$, to prevent division by zero, we can see the following:

$$\int\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n-1}}{n!}\:\mathrm{d}a=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}}{n\cdot n!}=\int\frac{e^{a}-1}{a}\:\mathrm{d}a=\operatorname{Ei}(a)-\ln(a)$$

Where $\operatorname{Ei}(a)$ is the [Exponential Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html) of $a$.